# Is there any way that I can show a input bar in html?

Tags: javascript, html

I made a website for a restaurant, the checkout page has 2 option, pay by cash and pay by card. Now if the user chooses to pay by card, then there will be no more input required. If the user chooses to pay by cash, then I need to let them enter their name. Is there any method I can show the input bar when the user chooses to pay by cash? I'm using python flask

Comment: Can you do it via JS?

Comment: @Spectric well I'm not really familiar with JS, but if there is no other way to do this I would like to learn it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JS to do it, since it is supported on nearly all browsers.

```js
function validate(){
  var cashpay = document.getElementById("cash-pay");
  var cardpay = document.getElementById("card-pay");
  var name = document.getElementById("name");
  if(cashpay.checked==true){
    name.style.display='block';
  }else{
    name.style.display='none';
  }
    
}
```

```css
.hidden{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<h1>What would you like to pay by?</h1>
<form>
<input type="radio" name="pay-method" id="cash-pay" oninput="validate()"><label for="cash-pay">Cash</label><input type="radio" name="pay-method" id="card-pay" oninput="validate()"><label for="card-pay">Card</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="hidden" placeholder="Please enter your name:">
</form>
```

We can use the `oninput` attribute in the input types to make sure that our JS function `validate()` is run every time the user modifies their choice. We can use the `.checked` DOM element to check whether the input is checked. If it is, we can use `.style.display='block'` to display the input.